# Shadow not being cast with ThreeJS in react-three-renderer

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm having trouble casting a shadow in my scene. Steps I've taken:

1. shadowMapEnabled attribute added to the React3 element
2. the directional light in my scene has verbatim the properties I [see here in the react-three-renderer example](https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer-example/blob/master/src/examples/Physics/mousePick.js)
3. all three meshes (one cube and two planes) in the scene have castShadow and receiveShadow

I have a black cube in the image below to show where the directional light is eminating from.

[image]

[Here's a gist of my code](https://gist.github.com/captDaylight/74deb87414ce76d6f77726989f716bff?ts=2). (abbreviated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the shadow camera's near value, it looks too high. If you can provide a full example it may be easier to diagnose what's happening

Additionally try to place a different object at the "lookAt" target for the light, this should help identify in which direction it will face

Comment: It ended up being the camera's near value. I'll have to read up on that because I'm not sure how that solved it!